# How to convert Multipage .pdf to Multipage .tiff in c# in window application using PDFSHARP

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Can any one help me how to convert Multipage .pdf to Multipage .tiff in c# in window application using PDFSHARP?

What are some methods I can call with buttons or some tutorials to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PDFsharp you cannot convert PDF to TIFF.

It's possible to convert TIFF to PDF (but that's off topic here).